# jQuery Gallery - Webkit problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay.  So I've got a a little jQuery gallery scroller I wrote to work with WordPress.  It works beautifully in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome or Safari.

Here's the link:

http://thehousinggroup.info/our-gallery/bathroom-renovations/gallery-1/

Here's the jQuery:

```
    var imageQuantity = $('.galleryBox img').size() //finds the number of images
    var wrapWidth = imageQuantity * 610 + 'px' //sets inner wrapper to image width*no. of images

    //Formating
    $('.galleryBox img')
        .hide()
        .unwrap()
        .wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
        .wrapAll('<div id="innerWrap"></div>')
        .wrap('<li></li>');//wraps images in ul and div, strips off the <p> that WordPress adds
    $('#innerWrap').css({
        'width' : wrapWidth,
        'position' : 'relative'
    });
    $('.galleryBox').css({'overflow' : 'hidden'}); //this css will be relegated to the stylesheet eventually...
    $('.galleryBox ul').css({'list-style' : 'none'});
    $('.galleryBox li').css({
        'float' : 'left',
        'margin-right' : '10px'
    });
    $('.galleryBox img').show(); //shows the images once the formatting is complete

    //Scroll Controls

    var currentNumber = 1; //this is for the "1 of 4" counter
    var fullNumber = imageQuantity;

    $('#innerWrap').before('<p id="scroller"><a id="prevButton" href="">previous</a> <span id="currentNumber">' + currentNumber + '</span> of ' + fullNumber +' <a id="nextButton" href="#">next</a></p>'); //this places the next, previous, and 1 of # counter buttons 
    $('#nextButton').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var wrapPosition = parseInt($('#innerWrap').css('right'));
        var stopPoint = (fullNumber-1)*610;
        if(wrapPosition < stopPoint) { //sets the scrolling to stop at last image
            $('#innerWrap').animate({'right' : "+=610px"});
            ++currentNumber;
            $('#currentNumber').empty().html(currentNumber); //sets the counter to the proper number
        }
    });
    $('#prevButton').click(function(event){ //same as above, reversed out for the previous button
        event.preventDefault();
        var wrapPosition = parseInt($('#innerWrap').css('right'));
        var stopPoint = (fullNumber-1)*610;
        if(wrapPosition > 0) {
            $('#innerWrap').animate({'right' : "-=610px"});
            --currentNumber;
            $('#currentNumber').empty().html(currentNumber);
        }

    });
```

I'm going to be setting the css to be in the stylesheets, but this is how it's set up for now.  If you've got any further critiques, I'm open!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line catches my attention:

`$('#innerWrap').animate({'right' : "-=610px"});`

Specially because there is no "right" property initially set up on WebKit.

Try to have the calculation done one step above:

```
right_pos = doTheMathHere;
$('#innerWrap').animate({'right' : rigt_pos});
```

Comment: "Specially because there is no "right" property initially set up on WebKit."

My problem was the one that I noticed--that the wrapping was wrong--but this was really the main issue.  All I had to do to correct the math was put `#innerWrap {right:0}` into my stylesheet and it works no problem.  Thanks Frankie.

Answer (score 0):

This code is breaking in Chrome : `var wrapPosition = parseInt($('#innerWrap').css('right'));`

So it's skipping over this block:

```
        if(wrapPosition < stopPoint) {
            $('#innerWrap').animate({'right' : "+=610px"});
            ++currentNumber;
            $('#currentNumber').empty().html(currentNumber);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question

I think I figured it out.  It has to do with the wrapAll() order.  I intended for the `<ul>` to be wrapped inside the `<div>`, but the opposite is happening.  This isn't a problem with Webkit.  It's more one of those..."wait...why does this work in Firefox" sorts of issues.